# Loop breaks even when conditions aren't met

Tags: java, loops

```
if (i== 0) {
    boolean goOn = false;
    do {
        int randy = (int) (Math.random()*people);
        System.out.println(workers[randy] + ": Sunday, 7-12");
        int randy1 = (int) (Math.random()*people);
        System.out.println(workers[randy1] + ": Sunday, 9-12");
        int randy2 = (int) (Math.random()*people);
        System.out.println(workers[randy2] + ": Sunday, 12-4");
        int randy3 = (int) (Math.random()*people);
        System.out.println(workers[randy3] + ": Sunday, 12-4");

        if (randy != randy1 && randy != randy2 && randy != randy3 && randy1 != randy2 && randy1 != randy3 && randy2 != randy3); {
            goOn = true;
        }
    } while (goOn==false);
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

If you look below, for some reason this loop continues even when one of the randomly generated numbers is equal to another. Kind of new to `Java` - just playing around, but why is this happening?

For context, `people` is an integer and and `workers[]` is a list of names.

Comment: It looks more like goOn is always true, therefore terminates immediatelly (which really makes the name for that variable strange). MAybe you better name it "hasCollision", and set it to true with or-checks: `if (randy == randy1 || randy == randy2 || ...) hasCollision=true;` better to read.

Comment: As normal practice, people don't do "goOn==false", they just do !goOn.

Comment: BTW: if you want to assign the 4 work slots randomly, you might better have a look at `Collections.shuffle()` instead. No need for you to loop.

Comment: BTW: if you use an IDE like eclipse and turn on all the warnings, it would print "Warning: Empty control-flow statement" on the line with the if-semicolon.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is here:

```
    if (randy != randy1 && randy != randy2 && randy != randy3 && randy1 != randy2 && randy1 != randy3 && randy2 != randy3); {
        goOn = true;
    }
```

The semicolon after your `if` parentheses completes the condition. As a result, the rest is always executed. Remove the semicolon and things should improve :)

(just to be precise what I mean: this is the right version plus some formatting)

```
    if (randy != randy1 
     && randy != randy2 
     && randy != randy3 
     && randy1 != randy2 
     && randy1 != randy3 
     && randy2 != randy3) {
        goOn = true;
    }
```